# JSON-HTTP to gRPC Transcoding

Tags: json, grpc, grpc-java, envoyproxy

I have a requirement to convert JSON to proto format which of course Envoy proxy does but i have to make few specific changes based on my project in it and develop on top of it.
So I wanted to know how should I go about it and which part in the envoy GitHub repo I should look at.
I am kinda stuck at this problem. So your help will be much appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this one https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/tree/master/source/extensions/filters/http/grpc_json_transcoder to get more info.

Comment: yeah i looked at it but i solved my problem using some other method thanks :)